# I need a 'selectedPrice' state that is available throughout all components, a slider that selects the price but state changes are breaking the slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is as follows

**App.jsx**

```
export default function App() {
  const [ showLayout, setShowLayout ] = useState(false)
  const [ selectedPrice, setSelectedPrice ] = useState(0)
  
  useEffect(
    () => {
      fetch('https://www.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          setSelectedPrice(parseInt(data.price))
          console.log(selectedPrice)
          console.log("Price Effect ran...")
        })
    },
    []
  )
  
  const props = {
    showLayout,
    setShowLayout,
    selectedPrice,
    setSelectedPrice
  }

  console.log("I am rendered...App")
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Chart
        {...props}
      />
      <Interface
        {...props}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Chart.jsx** which contains **VerticalSlider**

```
const VerticalSlider = React.forwardRef(({ currentPrice, setSelectedPrice, selectedPrice }, { candleSeriesRef, priceLineRef, chartRef }) => {
    const [ sliderValue, setSliderValue ] = useState(selectedPrice)
    const [ priceRange, setPriceRange ] = useState({})

    // this bit of code sets the maximum and minimum values of the slider as the user adjusts the chart scales
    if (showLayout) {
      candleSeriesRef.current.applyOptions({
        autoscaleInfoProvider: original => {
          const res = original();
          if (res !== null) {
            setPriceRange({
              minV: candleSeriesRef.current.coordinateToPrice(420),
              maxV: candleSeriesRef.current.coordinateToPrice(1)
            })
          }
          return res;
        }
      })
    }
    
    
    
    const handleSliderChange = (e, newValue) => {
      setSliderValue(newValue)
      priceLineRef.current.applyOptions({
        price: newValue
      })
      setSelectedPrice(newValue)
    }
    
    return (
      <>
        <div className='layout__vertical-slider'>
          <Slider
            min={ priceRange.minV }
            // min={ priceRange.minV }
            // max={ priceRange.maxV }
            max={ priceRange.maxV }
            value={ sliderValue }
            orientation="vertical"
            disabled={ showLayout ? false : true }
            onChange={handleSliderChange}
          />
        </div>
      </>
    )
})
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I define the state locally inside the VerticalSlider component, it works perfectly, however that's no good since I need the value of the state to be accessed by the whole application.

When I initialise the state inside App.jsx and pass it down, it triggers the whole App component to be rerendered and the slider gets reinitialised(?) on every rerender and loses focus.

Is there any workaround? My objective is to set the 'selectedPrice' state using the slider and access it from outside the component

I tried looking up all the documentation of the available hooks but couldn't find anything that would potentially solve my problem

Comment: You may want to look at [`React Contexts`](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context).

Comment: I did, it doesn't fix anything since the whenever the parent gets rerendered, the slider loses focus and gets reimplemented